# Math mode seems to depend on tikz and looks awful on epub

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ebook, epub

I have the following mcve.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 


\begin{document}

Hello World! 

$Hello World!$

\[ Hello World \]
\end{document}
```

If I run it through pdflatex it does exactly what I expect - "Hello world" in three slightly different styles:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However, I'm making an ebook, so I run it through tex4ebook and I get this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

...which is quite odd. But also if I happen to be using tikz (so I have \usepackage{tikz} at the top) it does render, but looks extremely bad:
[![enter image description here][3]][3] - I've tried it on bookworm, and mupdf, but most importantly on the official kdp kindle previewer, and on my own kindle.

Presumably this badness is because tikz is for some reason making a low quality png (indeed, one called mcve0x.png according to the log) instead of doing it properly.  Not only does it look bad here, it looks super bad on any actual ebook where, for example, it doesn't respond to font-size changes.

My question is: what is happening here and how to I get tex4ebook to produce maths that shows up nicely on an e-reader? Also - why is tikz getting involved?

EDIT - versions

- My TeX version is: pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
- My tex4ebook version is: v0.3g

EDIT - full debug log from tex4ebook

```
joe@joe-Amd-Am4-Home-Office:~/git/memorybook$ tex4ebook -a -debug -m draft mcve.tex
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: latex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname=mcve  
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: mcve.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: epub
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: mcve.tex
[INFO]    mkutils: Load extension   common_domfilters
[INFO]    tex4ebook: No conffile
[INFO]    mkutils: Cannot open config file  mcve.mk4
[INFO]    exec_epub: dir    mcve-epub/META-INF
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/META-INF/container.xml
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove dir mcve-epub/META-INF
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/mimetype
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/mcve.epub
[INFO]    exec_epub: dir    mcve-epub/OEBPS
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/OEBPS/content.opf
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/OEBPS/mcve.ncx
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/OEBPS/mcve.css
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove file    mcve-epub/OEBPS/mcve.html
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove dir mcve-epub/OEBPS
[INFO]    exec_epub: remove dir mcve-epub
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param ext
[WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found
[WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's
[INFO]    exec_epub: Output file: mcve.epub
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: latex --interaction=batchmode -jobname=mcve   '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}\RequirePackage{tex4ebook}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,,charset=utf-8,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{mcve.tex}"' > /dev/null 2>&1
[INFO]    mkutils:  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html
[INFO]    mkutils: executing: tex4ht  -cmozhtf -utf8 -cmozhtf -utf8 "mcve.dvi"
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht -cmozhtf 
  -utf8 
  -cmozhtf 
  -utf8 
  mcve.dvi 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/mozilla/charset/unicode.4hf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/cm/cmmi.htf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for `cmr10.htf'
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmrm.htf)
[1 file mcve.html
 file mcve.css
 file mcve.tmp
 file mcve.ncx
 file content.opf
 file content-part2.opf
]
Execute script `mcve.lg'

[INFO]    make4ht-lib: executing: t4ht  "mcve.dvi"
sh: 1: dvipng: not found
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2018-07-04-14:25 kpathsea)
t4ht mcve.dvi 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering mcve.lg
System call: dvipng -T tight -D 144 -bg Transparent -pp 2:2 mcve.idv -o mcve0x.png
--- Warning --- System return: 32512
Entering mcve.css
Entering mcve.tmp

[INFO]    mkutils: Parse LG
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: mcve.html
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: mcve.tmp
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "mcve.html" "mcve-epub/OEBPS"
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "mcve.css" "mcve-epub/OEBPS"
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for tmp is not registered
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "mcve.ncx" "mcve-epub/OEBPS"
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for opf is not registered
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for opf is not registered
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "mcve0x.png" "mcve-epub/OEBPS"
[ERROR]   mkutils: File mcve0x.png doesn't exist
cp: cannot stat 'mcve0x.png': No such file or directory
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "content.opf" "mcve-epub/OEBPS"
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.6.0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Tidy ncx 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Tidy opf 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack mimetype 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack metadir 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack outputdir 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Copy generated epub 
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "mcve-epub/mcve.epub" "mcve.epub"
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
joe@joe-Amd-Am4-Home-Office:~/git/memorybook$
```

Comment: This is a tex4ebook question.  About all we can do is help youj make higher res images for the display math.

Comment: I don't think EPUB supports math to begin with, so some embedding technique has to be used and tex4ebook choses to render PNG. See also https://github.com/w3c/epub-specs/issues/845

Comment: The way epub is rendered will always vary, from browser to browser, computer to computer, OS to operating system, over time etc. You have zero guarantee about the look and feel.

Comment: Which Epub reader do you use? With TikZ, you get SVG output, which is vector format and should have much better quality than PNG. It is possible that your reader doesn't support it well.

Comment: @michal.h21 I've added details of the four that I've tried to the question.

Comment: @JohnKormylo is tex4ebook not covered on tex SE? I was confused because there is a tag...

Comment: It is really strange that you get PNG images with TikZ, it requires the SVG output. Which TeX distro do you use?

Comment: @michal.h21 - I've added the versions.

Comment: these versions are slightly old, but they shouldn't produce the wrong results.

Comment: Incidentally, I got similar request few days ago, maybe the Lua code can help: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/issues/113

Comment: @michal.h21 responding to the bit about png images with tikz - that's confusing me as well - but I'm more confused about the [image] tag I get if I don't include tikz... any ideas?

Comment: No, this shouldn't happen, image conversion worked always in TeX4ht, this is the basic functionality. Could you post the full output from `tex4ebook -a debug -m draft mcwe.tex`?

Comment: @michal.h21 done :)

Comment: ah, I see what is the problem: `sh: 1: dvipng: not found`. You need to install the `dvipng` command.

Comment: @michal.h21 - thank you! That solved the missing image problem, which is nice, but I'm stuck wondering why the centred math mode is an image?

Comment: display math is converted to images by default, as opposed to inline math, which is converted to mix of HTML + images for more complex stuff. You can try to convert math to MathML (using `tex4ebook -f epub3 filename.tex "mathml"), which should have better quality, but support in Epub readers is not good. Some of them (especially older e-ink devices) don't support it at all.